# Pylint error with valid code inside class

Tags: python, class, pylint

I have set up an reentrant lock (RLock) in a class like so inside the init function:

```
self.lock= threading.RLock()
```

If I try to get a count of the locks like so:

```
self.lock._RLock__count
```

I get this error with pylint:

```
E:581,15: Instance of '_RLock' has no '_RLock__count' member (no-member)
```

The code works fine, I only have a problem passing pylint testing, do I have to tell it to ignore this like a dynamic attribute?

Comment: Variable names starting with a single underscore are conventionally used to signal that the attribute should not be accessed outside of the class' definition, so it would make sense that Pylint would complain. But it's still entirely possible to ignore the convention and access the value anyway, so it's curious that it would be considered an error rather than a warning.

Comment: @Kevin It is also strange because I have no problem accessing the value from outside the class and pylint does not give an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a limitation of pylint, I disabled the error locally with the below comment/command and everything works fine:

```
# pylint: disable=E1101
```